# Не работает установка опции в vimrc

Tags: vim, vimrc

Каждый раз при запуске Vim (через cmd или двойным кликом по vim.exe) вижу окно с текстом *"Нажмите ENTER или введите команду для продолжения"* посередине. Поискав в Интернете, я увидел решение этой проблемы - предлагают добавить строку `"set shortmess=a"` в файл vimrc. Но после добавления этой строки в файл и последующем запуске значение опции shortmess не изменилось, и при вводе команды `":set shortmess?"` я вижу ответ `"shortmess=filnxtToO"`. Что я делаю не так?

Сам Vim расположен по пути `D:\Vim`
Файл vimrc, который я редактирую, находится в `C:\Users\USERNAME\_vimrc`

Comment: Не могу воизпрозвести, ни с кликом, ни в cmd, всё работает. Вам действительно нужен vim в cmd окне? Вы при установке указали, что надо .bat создать?

Comment: Не обязательно в cmd окне, такая проблема появляется при любом запуске Vim из откуда-либо. Насчет создания bat не помню, разве в установщике была такая опция?

Comment: Не совсем понял. Если вы запускаете в cmd, где тогда vim выполняется?

Comment: В случае с запуском cmd, он выполняется в окне cmd, но на мой взгляд, это не имеет значения, поскольку при запуске vim.exe из проводника происходит абсолютно то же, что и при запуске через cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле, как мне удалось выяснить, это не одна, а две проблемы. Прежде всего, многие инструкции set в файле _vimrc не имеют должного эффекта, будучи написанными перед инструкцией `set nocompatible`. Эта инструкция перезаписывает некоторые опции, в том числе и `shortmess`, придавая им значения по умолчанию.
Кроме этого, также эта проблема может проявляться из-за ошибок, допущенных в файле _vimrc. Эти сообщения об ошибках можно посмотреть, воспользовавшись командой `:messages`. Если ошибок нет, то эта команда должна показывать только автора программы/переводчиков на ваш язык.